# Using font in android commercial (paid) app

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, licensing

I like to use a custom font FiraSans in a Android commercial (paid) app.
Besides the SIL Open Font License.txt in the font directory location ..
Do I need as mandatory to add anything else like:

- Link to open this file from inside app like the About dialog?
- Show the Copyright info that is found?

Or this is optional?

> Copyright (c) 2014, Mozilla Foundation https://mozilla.org/ with
>   Reserved Font Name Fira Sans.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow not many people cares about this! Good boy :D
Well what you are doing should be enough add a license file together with the font as you mentioned and the copyright under about

> Original or Modified Versions of the Font Software may be bundled,
>   redistributed and/or sold with any software, provided that each copy
>   contains the above copyright notice and this license. These can be
>   included either as stand-alone text files, human-readable headers or
>   in the appropriate machine-readable metadata fields within text or
>   binary files as long as those fields can be easily viewed by the user.

From http://www.fontsquirrel.com/license/fira-sans